# Find Unique Hbase Prefix Keys with Java

Tags: java, hbase

I'm using Java to query an hbase table with keys that look like this:

```
a.1
b.1
b.2
c.1
c.2
```

I want to search for anything that starts with a or b, and I only want to return a unique value for the prefix. So my api would return a list: `[a, b]`, not `[a,b,b]`.

My approach so far has been to

1. create a `Scan` between `a` and `c`.
2. iterate over each result, do a split on the `.`
3. use a `Set` to make sure I don't have any duplicates
4. return the `Set` as a `List`

This works fine, except in this case:

```
a.1
b.1
b.2
...
b.10000000
c.1
```

In this case, I have far too many keys to iterate through, that I don't care about because i already have a `b`. My application is timing out before finishing.

My question is, is there a filter I can apply in my scan to only get unique values of a range of prefixes? Can I tell Hbase to skip to the next match without having to create a new scan? I'd rather not create a new table with only the values I'm looking for, because another portion of the application is using the whole key, so both aspects are valuable.

Comment: Asking databases to perform logical aggregation operations on selection is fine, but this seems to be much a customized requirement.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use the existing row filtering capabilities to accomplish this?  Please ensure you have read all the HBase documentation and explain what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HBase's `MultiRowRangeFilter`. I think for your case you could try to pass a collection of `RowRange` elements, each of which can limit the start and stop row criteria with enough granularity to fit your use-case.

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/MultiRowRangeFilter.html

I haven't used it enough to comment on the performance, but it's worth a try given you already have something to compare against.